# Show/hide a div depending on if cursor is in a text field

Tags: javascript, input, textarea, show-hide, quill

I have an input text field, and it has a formatting bar above it.
I want to hide the bar when the cursor isn't in the input field.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdzvey7g/) for anyone who is able to help.

```
<div class="header-div">
This is my header div
</div>

<div >
<input placeholder="placeholder text">
</div>

<p class="explainer">
When I've clicked in the input box above (ready to type or currently typing), I want the grey bar above to show, otherwise hide it.
</p>
```

Note that I'm using Quill for the rich text input, but just want to know the general javascript syntax/concept anyway of how to detect when the input field is active, so it can affect other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create listeners for the `focus` and `blur` events on the textbox and update the style to show/hide the header. The code below should get you started:

```js
let textbox = document.querySelector('input');
let header = document.querySelector('.header-div');

// add event listeners to textbox
textbox.addEventListener('focus', function() { 
    toggleDisplay(header, true);
});
textbox.addEventListener('blur', function() { 
    toggleDisplay(header, false);
});

function toggleDisplay(element, show) {
    if (show) 
        element.style.display = 'block';
    else
        element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.header-div {
  display: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius:6px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}

.explainer {
  color:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-div">
  This is my header div
</div>

<div >
  <input placeholder="placeholder text">
</div>

<p class="explainer">
  When I've clicked in the input box (ready to type or currently typing), I want   the grey bar above to show, otherwise hide it.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope it's help full for you.

```js
$('#myinp').on('focus blur',function(e){
if(e.type=='focus'){
$('.header-div').css('display','block');
}else{
$('.header-div').css('display','none');
}
});
```

```css
.header-div{
  display:none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius:6px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}
.explainer{
  color:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-div">
This is my header div
</div>

<div >
<input id='myinp' placeholder="placeholder text">
</div>

<p class="explainer">
When I've clicked in the input box (ready to type or currently typing), I want the grey bar above to show, otherwise hide it.
</p>
```